# Samsung stuck at animation logo

Tags: samsung

When I try to turn on my GTS6312 this happens :-

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b7eBNPs2Oyvfs41c1BwzVSp4uEjCEErs/view?usp=drivesdk

I can not boot into recovery. I flashed the stock ROM but it does not solve my problem.
It just stucks on the samsung constantly glowing animation.

Comment: Probably a hardware failure. You should try flashing a repair firmware and see if it can solve this. Just Google for `gt-s6312 4 files firmware`

Comment: @esQmo_ post this in answer it is a completely correct answer. I will tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this can be caused by either a hardware failure or simply a software error, also called a soft brick.

If your hardware is damaged, e.g. the eMMC chip is damaged, there is no much you can do than sending the phone to a repair shop.

In other hand, the software failure can be ''repaired" by flashing the device with a full firmware, aka `4 files firmware`, this cam be found online. Then simply flash it with Odin or any flashing software and your soft brick  should be solved.

Comment: You are welcome